# barplot for xts objects

Tags: r, xts

Can I use barplot to plot xts objects? Or is there any similar function that I can use? quantmod is not what I'm talking about since it's not flexible enough and not compatible with other R graphics.

Comment: any solution in base R plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the indices and the values 
of an xts or zoo object with `index` 
and `coredata`: this should suffice 
to plot it the way you want.

```
# Sample data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")
x <- Vo( GSPC )

# Base graphics
plot( index(x), coredata(x), type="h" )

# ggplot2
d <- data.frame( time=index(x), volume=drop(coredata(x)) )
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(time, volume)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: thank u so much! that inspires me and just by changing this a little bit serves the purpose in my context~~

Comment: i am getting this error.. could not find function "barplot.xts" .. am I missing some package? It was working till date.