# polygon for xts objects

Tags: r, xts

Can I use polygon to plot xts objects? Or is there any similar function that I can use? I am asking this since I want to fill colours under certain curves (equity curves, say) which are plotted using xts package. Thx!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582033/barplot-for-xts-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the indices and the values 
of an xts object with `index` 
and `coredata`.

```
# Sample data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")
x <- Vo(GSPC)
n <- length(x)

# Plot
plot(index(x), coredata(x), type="n", las=1, ylim=range(0,x))
polygon( 
  index(x)[c(1,1:n,n)], 
  c(0,coredata(x),0), 
  col="grey" 
)
box()
```

Comment: Thx again, Vincent! You may notice that this should not be a question any more since a similar question has been solved. But, the situation here is a little bit different. In fact, the code given by you do not display the scale. I've tried the following code, in which case scale can be displayed correctly, but the side effect is that polygon seems not working:

library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")
x <- Vo(GSPC)
n <- length(x)

# Plot
plot(as.xts(x), type="l", las=1, ylim=range(0,x))
polygon( 
  index(x)[c(1,1:n,n)], 
  c(0,coredata(x),0), 
  col="grey" 
)
box()

Answer (score 0):

Use `xts::`[`addPolygon`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xts/versions/0.10-0/topics/addPolygon), in which coordinates of polygon must be provided as an xts matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!